# Views using inline values in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We sometimes create tables/dimensions with small ***static*** datasets (the values never change) by suppling the values inline using a `VALUES` clause, like this (simplified):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES
  (1, 2, 3),
  (4, 5, 6);
```

However, a colleague just realized we could also create them as views just the same:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES
  (1, 2, 3),
  (4, 5, 6);
```

It works, but I'm wondering about the implications of using a view instead of a table. I’m mostly looking for any community/expert input on whether this is a good idea or not, and why. Just want to make sure we're not missing anything!

Some thoughts:

- Reading from the table implies reading data from cloud storage or Snowflake cache.
- But when reading from the view, the data is simply fetched from the view definition each time? (with possible cache on top)

  - This seems to be confirmed by the fact that queries to this view have no "Bytes Scanned" in the query history.
- Obviously, the view data can't be modified unless we replace the view, which is expected (and kind of a good thing).
- For these datasets, we don't really care about table data retention (we could easily re-create them if needed).
- The performance is good in both cases (which is not surprising for such small datasets).

***Edit:*** Thank you for the two great answers! I wish I could accept both. It's probably better to just stick with tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a tiny dataset like your example, the performance won't be different so much between a table and a (constant) view. We usually use a subquery/CTE with a small dataset using `VALUES` or `GENERATOR`, which are typically performant enough. The view usage is very similar to the subquery/CTE, so I have no concern about creating the tiny dataset with a constant view.

---

In contrast, if the dataset is huge, I'd prefer to use a table rather than a view because a table will have much better performance than a view.

Below are some examples that a view may have worse performance than a table. Please note that this is not an exclusive list of performance differences; There may be other situations/corner cases causing performance differences between a table and a constant view.

In the examples, I'll use the below dummy data that contains 1 billion sequential integer values. It's almost the same as listing 1 billion values in the `VALUES` clause (except the cost of parse/compilation).

```sql
create or replace table test_t1b (c1 int) as
select seq4() from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000000));

create or replace view test_v1b as
select seq4() c1 from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000000));
```

Also, I used an XSMALL warehouse for all the examples.

**(1) Partition pruning is not applied to a constant view**

Since the constant view is not a table, the values are generated while running the query; it cannot benefit from partition pruning.

```sql
select * from test_t1b where c1 < 1000;
-- 171 ms

select * from test_t1b where c1 = 1000;
-- 172 ms

select * from test_v1b where c1 < 1000;
-- 588 ms

select * from test_v1b where c1 = 1000;
-- 597 ms
```

In the above examples, the queries on the table (`test_t1b`) only scans 1 partition out of 200+ partitions, but the queries on the view (`test_v1b`) always have to generate 1 billion rows and then filter.

**(2) Metadata queries don't work on a constant view**

Snowflake can get the result of several functions like `MAX()`, `MIN()`, and `COUNT()` from the table metadata without query execution.

However, the constant view doesn't have such metadata, so the functions always have to calculate the result from the generated dataset.

```sql
select max(c1), min(c1), count(*) from test_t1b;
-- 45 ms

select max(c1), min(c1), count(*) from test_v1b;
-- 797 ms
```

---

In conclusion, if the dataset contains just several rows, your analysis is totally correct; You can feel free to use a view to generate the dataset. Otherwise, a physical table would be preferred because it benefits from various optimizations only applied to physical tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of considerations here

1. Is it ideal to be hardcoding values?
2. How many values will there be, does the value change?

A lookup table should be established and managed as part of a reference data framework, using a few values is fine for Snowflake and compiles quickly and is used in filtering. Should that list grow then managing it in the code becomes cumbersome and worse if the list contains a thousand items using it in a subsequent IN statement does not compile well --- if you are thinking of using that. Instead a table can be used to do dynamic pruning, that is, it is used in a join statement to achieve the subsetting / filtering you desire. As long as the queries themselves are preferably conjunctive, even better if it is an equijoin.

In terms of caching there's a number of factors,

1. is it the first query?
2. How complex the query is?
3. Are you testing the query by turning resultcache off and flushing your virtual warehouse?

These all impact how much is scanned from memory.

Resultset is available for 24 hours but only used after the first query and the subsequent query using that resultset must be identical to that first query and not use context functions like current_time

The second level cache lives in the virtual warehouse, those are virtual machines and therefore contain cache and their own SSD. Again it uses the second query, it could also be the first query but through its adaptive caching mechanisms use the cache to answer your query --- but typically you'd see a very low % cache used in this instance. If it is the 2nd query then the % is higher.

All these things are enabled by default, virtual warehouse cache lives for as long as the VM is running -- that you set.